# Hadoop: Got error creating database manager

Tags: sql, linux, hadoop, vertica

when I tried to run a sqoop commmand, I get an error saying no manager for connect string

What I try to run:

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:vertica://xxxxxxxx.com:5433/PPS_GIIA" --username xxxxx --password      
xxxxx --table Country -m 1 --export-dir /Eservices/SIPOC/SQLimport/part-m-0000 --input-  
fields- terminated-by ',' --lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

The error that I get:

```
WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P         
instead.ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No    
manager for connect string: jdbc:vertica://xxx:5637/xxx at                                                              
org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:185)
```

I've already copied the Vertica driver and placed it in /sqoop-1.4.3/lib. Anyone has idea what caused this?

Comment: fwiw, the hostname is still showing in your error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing driver in the command line. It should be of the form:

```
--driver <jdbc driver fully qualified class>
--driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
```